# Can't make MatPlotLib display mid-function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am writing a programme to input data into a JSON database. Part of this is:

- displaying an image (file name entered by user)
- asking for coordinates of interest (entered by user)
- re-displaying cropped image using those coordinates
- asking for tags for this cropped segment (entered by user)
- saving tags & coordinates in the JSON database

This same process was used for text files but now that I am doing images I am having the problem that when my programme calls the function:

```html
img = mpimg.imread("raw_data" + system_slash + "images" + system_slash + database[i]['image_file']) 
plot.imshow(img)
```

it does not display the image immediately, but instead only after the whole programme completes. Could anyone suggest a different call to make it display in line, like a print function for text?

*the system slash is a quick and dirty fix for me and my colleague using both PC and MAC file systems when using the programme, so either / or \

Comment: Put `plt.pause(0.1)` after the plotting command and see if it works

Comment: That works! Thanks!

Comment: @user8408080 tbh I would add as an answer and explain why it works.

Comment: @roganjosh Yes, sorry, I was on mobile. I put an answer here now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the plotting command, you should put [`matplotlib.pyplot.pause(t)`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pause.html), where `t` is the time you want to pause. The interval `t` is in seconds, so if you want for example an animation with roughly 60fps, you could set `t=1/60`.

The function updates the figure and displays it for `t` seconds.

**EDIT** What also came to my mind is: Don't call `plt.imshow` repeatedly. This is very slow. Better call it once and then just set the data. Little demo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

im = plt.imshow(np.random.rand(10,10))

while True:
    im.set_data(np.random.rand(10,10))
    plt.pause(1/10)
```

Comment: As this is a new question, you should create a new question and accept this answer. Having multiple questions in one post is not a good practice here. Also, that way your question will get more attention. I'm turning on my PC rn to see if I get the same problem :) just send me a link to your new question

Comment: Actually I can move the window freely and resize it. You should also post your version of matplotlib and your OS in the new question